# How to store vector in dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a dataframe through a for loop and trying to add a vector for each row of the data frame.

The rows are people and the columns are the name category and points category.

For example I'm trying to have something like...

```
Name  Points
Susie c(12,45,23)
Bill  c(13,24,12,89)
CJ    c(12)
```

So far my code looks like

```
names_list <-c("Susie","Bill","CJ")
result = data.frame()

for (name in names_list){
    listing = .....
    frame = data.frame(name,listing)
    names(frame) = c("name","list")
    result <- rbind(result,frame)
}
```

Where listing happens to be the points associated with that name. However instead of creating 1 row for each name containing all their points, it creates multiple rows with the same name for each point.

Result looks like

```
1 Susie    12
2 Susie    45
3 Susie    23
4  Bill    13
5  Bill    24
6  Bill    12
7  Bill    89
8    CJ    12
```

Comment: What about `L <- list(Susie=c(12,45,23), Bill=c(13,24,12,89), CJ=c(12));
data.frame(Name=rep(names(L), lengths(L)), Points=unlist(L))` ?

Comment: Add a row at a time to a data.frame is a very inefficient operation. See [Circle 2 of the R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). And storing vectors in data.frames can make the data.frame much harder to work with (you can't read/write it to disk anymore). Maybe take a step back and tell us what you are really trying to do and we can suggest better (more R-like) ways to do it.

Comment: Basically I have a bunch of people who have points associated with them. I want to eventually run tests of normality of those points to test if each person's point follows a normal distribution. I wanted to store those points in a dataframe so I could call them up when I iterate through those people. This is the first time I've worked with R so there probably is a better solution than what I'm doing.

Comment: The format you got (rather than the one you want) will be much easier to use with built in statistical tests in R. Nested data structure aren’t the norm when working with base R functions.

Answer (score 12):

The specific problem you've encountered is due to `data.frame` flattening any list inputs. This can be prevented using the identify function `I`. For example,

```
data.frame(a = 1, b = list(c("a", "b")))
```

doesn't do what you want, but

```
data.frame(a = 1, b = I(list(c("a", "b"))))
```

does. A discussion of this behavior and some alternatives are available at http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1

You can use `I` to produce the desired result using your example as well:

```
names_list <-c("Susie","Bill","CJ")
points <- list(c(12,45,23),
               c(13,24,12,89),
               12)

result = data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(names_list)){
    frame = data.frame(names_list[[i]], I(points[i]))
    names(frame) = c("name","list")
    result <- rbind(result,frame)
}
```

though as pointed out in the comments, there are better ways to do it. All you really need is

```
data.frame(
    name = names_list,
    points = I(points))
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know in what structure your vector value sare but in general to nest vectors in a column you can do something like this:

```
names <- c("A", "B", "C")
vectors <- list(list(1,2,3), list(4,5,6), list(7,8,9))
as.data.frame(cbind(names, vectors))

   names vectors
 1     A 1, 2, 3
 2     B 4, 5, 6
 3     C 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: Brilliant! I have been looking for this answer for years! Dataframes are so useful, but I have encountered the posted problem regarding vectors so many times. I have never seen a practical solution until this. Thank you! If a better solution exists, I would be thrilled to see it. An explanation of why this works would be helpful, too.

Comment: vectors <- list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9)) works well too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Name   <- c("Suzie", "Bill", "CJ")
Points <- list(c(   12,45,23),
               c(13,24,12,89),
               c(         12)
           )
result <- as.data.frame(cbind(Name, Points))
```

Then:

```
print(result)
```

Gives:

```
> result
   Name         Points
1 Suzie     12, 45, 23
2  Bill 13, 24, 12, 89
3    CJ             12
```

Note:

```
print(result$Points)
```

Gives:

```
> result$Points
[[1]]
[1] 12 45 23

[[2]]
[1] 13 24 12 89

[[3]]
[1] 12
```